# Adding Text to FileName

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting, variables

I am using the filename for other inputs (so I can't rename it) but just want to add the text "Shopping List" to the filename which is refering to a date. Picture and code below describing intention.

```
Sub Calcs()
filename As String

filename = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)
    Worksheets("4. Grocery Store").Range("$A$1").Value = filename

'Bunch of code here

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This sounds like what you're looking for. If not then I'll need further clarification.

Worksheets("4. Grocery Store").Range("$A$1").Value = "Shopping List " & filename

Comment: What is initially in A1? Is this worksheet in the workbook containing this code? What is the exact name of a file? It can't be named `5/10/23` (it can easily be reformatted). Is there a newline character between `Shopping List` and the date? Please add this and any other information to your post.

Comment: @Jim Becker thanks that is all I wanted to do. I forgot about the syntax & relation to the excel grid system and VBA (they do the same thing).